# git merge 2 repositories

Tags: git, merge, repository

long time ago I created a git repo for my project where I stored all my sourcecodes. Then I created another repo for the documentation. Now when I look back, it was a stupid idea to separate them in 2 different repos.
So now I want to merge these 2 repos with their complete history into one repo with each of them in a subfolder:

```
/myprojectname/
              /sourcecode/
              /documentation/
```

Is it possible to do this? And how?

Comment: Probably duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories).

Comment: I'm not trying to add one repo as subfolder to the other one. but both in the same directory as subfolders to the main folder

Comment: do you have other files in `myprojectname` that are being tracked by git?

Comment: I hope I can explain it properly... I would do something like `git mkdir myprojectname`, `cd /myprojectname`, `git init` to create the my new projectfolder, and then somehow get my 2 old separated projects which contains code/documentation as subfolder with their history. So if I `git log` in the `myprojectname`, it would show me the history of the history from both old projects. Is it possible?